# apache config tell WP install location magento 2 xampp windows

Tags: php, wordpress, magento, magento2, fishpig

Working on local xampp install of Magento 2.4.2 on Windows 11.
I'm a Magento newbie - made it past several common Windows install issues but getting stuck with how to tell Apache where WP install is located. This install is a dev site, not sample Magento install.

Wordpress is integrated via Fishpig and below are some details to be entered inside server{} of nginx.conf file per dev setup docs.

```
# WordPress is installed in pub/wp
location /wp/ {
index index.html index.php;
try_files $uri $uri/ /wp/index.php?q=$uri&args;
location ~ \.php$ {
fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9074;
fastcgi_index /wp/index.php;
include fastcgi.conf;
}
}
```

I tried that actually, but I'm using xampp & Apache not nginx for this install.
I'm currently getting "WordPress doesn't appear to be installed" error at base url.

So my question is - where / how can I enter this info in Apache config? Or is there a different solution?
I looked into several .htaccess files but that doesn't seem to be the right place unless I reformat the details.

Answer (score 0):

Unlike Nginx, you don't actually have to configure individual routes to different applications. If you have set your public root directory and that points to Magento, you don't then need to add extra configs for WordPress.

Just install WordPress in a subfolder of Magento, something like 'wp'.

Let's say you have Magento installed and can browse it on the URL:

https://local.yourstore.com/

If you then install WordPress in a subfolder called 'wp' you should be able to run the installer at:

https://local.yourstore.com/wp/

This will work automatically without any extra config in Apache to get this working.

One thing to ensure is that you have Magento running from /pub and WordPress is installed in pub/wp.

If you install WordPress in a different folder, you will need to modify the path in the FishPig module config in the Magento Admin as 'wp' is the default value used.